Equivalent ways to obtain the reduced closed subscheme associated to the whole space
Let $(X,O_X)$ be a scheme. Consider the sheaf of ideals $I$ defined by: $$I(U)=\{s\in O_X(U):s_x\in \mathrm{nil}(O_{X,x})$$ $$\forall x\in U\},$$ for any open set $U\subset X$.
I know that $(X,O_X/I)$ is the unique reduced closed subscheme of $(X,O_X)$ with underlying space $X$.
However from 26.12.4 in the Stacks Project I see that the unique reduced closed subscheme of $(X,O_X)$, with underlying space $X$, is $(X,O_X/J)$, where the sheaf of ideals $J$ is defined by:
$$J(U)=\{s\in O_X(U):s_x\in \mathfrak m_x$$ $$\forall x\in U\},$$ where $\mathfrak m_x$ is the maximal ideal of $O_{X,x}$.
Since the structure of reduced closed subscheme on $X$ is indeed unique, the two sheaves of ideals $I$ and $J$ should coincide; however the maximal ideal and the nilradical of a local ring don't coincide in general, so I cant explain to myself how come $J$ and $I$ are associated to the same closed subscheme.
I hope that I have been clear with my issue, thanks in advance.

The two conditions defining these ideals are equivalent. Let $s\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ be a section.
$\Rightarrow$: if $s_x\in \operatorname{nil}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ for all $x\in U$, then as every nilpotent element of a ring belongs to every prime ideal, we have $s_x\in\mathfrak{m}_x$ for all $x\in U$.
$\Leftarrow$: pick $x\in u$ and let $x\in\operatorname{Spec} A\subset U$ be an affine open neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U$. Then $s|_{\operatorname{Spec} A}$ is some element of $A$, call it $a$, such that $a_\mathfrak{p}\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$. But this implies $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$, and the intersection of all primes is exactly the nilradical, so in fact $a\in \operatorname{nil}(A)$, and since this is preserved by localization, in fact $a_\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{nil}(A_\mathfrak{p})$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$. So we have $s_x\in\operatorname{nil}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ and since $x$ was arbitrary, we see that $s_x\in\operatorname{nil}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ for all $x\in U$.
